# Validation of one attribute with Hibernate validator

Tags: java, validation, constraints, hibernate-validator

Good evening, I'm trying to use Hibernate Validator, in the following scenario:

```
public class Car {

@NotNull
private String manufacturer;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 2, max = 14)
private String licensePlate;

@Min(2)
private int seatCount;

//setters and getters....
}
```

and I am trying to validate its attributes as follows:

```
public class CarMain {

public static Validator validator;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation. buildDefaultValidatorFactory() ;
    validator = factory. getValidator();
    Car car = new Car(null,null,0);
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Car>> st= validator.validate(car);
    while(st.iterator.hasNext()){
        ConstraintViolation<Car> cv = st.iterator.next();
        System.out.println("Value: ("+cv.getInvalidValue()+") -->"+cv.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Attribute: "+cv.getPropertyPath());
    }
}
```

Here the whole entity is validated and the invalid values with the validation message and property path are displayed.

My question is:"Is it possible to validate only one attribute at a time with Hibernate Validator? Like I don't have to work with the whole object to validate it.

Answer (score 0):

The `Validator` interface defines also a `[Validator.validateProperty][1]` method where you explicitly specify the property to validate. Mind you, you still need the object instance and you need to know the property you want to validate. This method is for example used by the integration of Bean Validation into JSF. Whether it makes sense to use it inm your case, will depend on your use case? Why don't you want to validate the whole object?

BTW, there is also `Validator.validateValue` which does not require an actual bean instance.

Comment: I have to use this validator in an algorithm that uses only one chosen attribute at a time, so I don't need the whole instance,,thank you so much,,
and there is one more thing if you please: it is not possible to change the constraint of an attribute for example : @Min(2) to @Min(4) !!! only if we changed the whole class,, am i right ? or is there anything else we can do ??
thank you so much your answer is helpful sir.